# For a type T (as a set of properties), how to create a type V minus U, which is a subset of T?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, subset

I have an interface `Abcd` with several properties:

```
interface Abcd {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: boolean
  d: string
}
```

I would like to define a type `Options` for an object passed as a parameter to a function `setOptions`. In the `options` object, there are two properties:

1. `fn` is an asynchronous callback that returns a subset of properties of `Abcd`.
2. `remaining` is an object that contains the remaining properties that are missing in the return type of `fn`.

Like this:

```
setOptions<Abcd>({
  fn: async () => ({ a: "aaa" }),
  remaining: {
    b: 123,
    c: false,
    d: "ddd",
  }
})
```

Is it possible to ensure that, if `fn` returns the property `a`, then `remaining` should not contain it? The type should also complain if a property is missing in both `remaining` and the return value of `fn`. And it should refuse extra properties.

For example:

```
setOptions<Abcd>({
  fn: async () => ({ a: "aaa" }),
  remaining: { // error, missing property `d`
    a: "aaa", // error, `a` is already in the return type of `fn`
    b: "bbb", // error, type of `b` should be 'number'
    c: false,
    e: "extra prop", // error, `e` is not in `Abcd`
  }
})
```

I tried:

```
interface Options<T extends object, U = Partial<T>, V = Omit<T, keyof U>> {
  fn: () => Promise<U>
  remaining: V
}

function setOptions<T extends object>(options: Options<T>) {
}
```

It is is my closest attempt, but it is not the solution.

To help: the same code [in the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM4A8AKshAB6QgAmey2ARgFYQJgA0yAqsgLzIAKcKFjgAbYgD4OANV5oAtsDDEOAawgBPbDC4SJyAN4BYAFDJkMEAC5kACgCUvffyjZFeCAU4TT5qBHk4UFAAcxtpUwBfU1MYAFcQVhwQZA8wDCxcQhJySho6JhYwCVtsTGS8GwyKyUdjE2iTU1BIWEQUAEF6BCpDX2Q4GzwwKFD++hsQOPl6aH6EG3psbFEIOBB+qiGRsYaYkzTqrIIunpL680sbODwNRLtHHn1bAwGbACI4L-fkSPs2fr+QLBEBhPpmczICbIACMACYAMwAiHmBYWMQeZGQ5BbZDvKgE95Y35ReymIA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Without type inference for `K`**

```
interface Options<T extends object, K extends keyof T> {
  fn: () => Promise<Pick<T, K>>;
  remaining: Omit<T, K>
}

function setOptions<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(options: Options<T, K>) {}

interface Abcd {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: boolean
  d: string
}

setOptions<Abcd, 'a'>({
  fn: async () => ({ a: "aaa" }),
  remaining: {
    b: 123,
    c: false,
    d: "ddd",
  }
})
```

**With type inference for `K`**

You need an extra function call:

```
const setOptions = <T extends object>() =>
  <K extends keyof T>(source: {
    fn: () => Promise<Pick<T, K>>;
    remaining: Omit<T, K>
  }) => { }
  
interface Abcd {
  a: string
  b: number
  c: boolean
  d: string
}

setOptions<Abcd>()({
  fn: async () => ({ a: '' }),
  remaining: {
    b: 1,
    c: false,
    d: "ddd",
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUDyAHKBLcEYF4YB4AVGeADynjABNsQAjAK3mCgD4AKASl1YFgAoGAQDSJcpRowA1vACeIAGYxCHCCACuAJ2DwAXDADeAoUIVh9XHjAAKmkAFt0CfNfTApRADQxhrVgG5jE014ewBDdDBIgHN9JEcoLx8+QRgAX24cVkN0oIFIik0FMJ0YAEE6YCpDILD9aE0YoLp9MHV7OnhNIOB9OhAQABt4MLAgqnqoRrBogTSBAQRkNExIfAqqjk52I1SzfTCIWTBgGEsss4MYOpgAclv0zk8gkPDImP1dk2v9e+8Aen+MAAwg4UOhhgBaDD2eAkTR2TRnaIDKicIJCFowACMz1SQl6MGKgwQeO+ExgACIqDTKWTcvwMgt+EA)

Comment: Thank you. But I really need that `'a'` is inferred from the return type of `fn`.

Comment: Thank you. It would be nice if the TypeScript team solves [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571) to avoid the ugly hack of a useless function returning a function.